# d3.js (v4) Scatter w/ Tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I'm building a scatter plot visualization in d3, but I'm having a slight problem displaying point tooltips. The data exists as an array object, where the element in position 0 is the `x` coordinate, position 1 the `y` coordinate, position 2 the point `cluster`, and position 3 the `cluster description`.

```
[
  {
    "points": [
      [
        -12.32, 
        15.74, 
        1, 
        "Cluster 5"
      ], ... , 
      [
        -15.38, 
        -3.97, 
        0, 
        "Cluster 2"
      ]
  }
]
```

Here is my JS:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data) {

  var points = data[0].points;

  var svg = d3.select("#cluster"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height");

  var k = height / width,
      x0 = [-15, 15],
      y0 = [-15 * k, 15 * k],
      x = d3.scaleLinear().domain(x0).range([0, width]),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(y0).range([height, 0]),
      z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var xAxis = d3.axisTop(x).ticks(12),
      yAxis = d3.axisRight(y).ticks(12 * height / width);

  var brush = d3.brush().on("end", brushended),
      idleTimeout,
      idleDelay = 350;

  var tooltip = d3.select("#cluster")
      .append("div")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", "10")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .style("background", "#ffffff")
      .text("a simple tooltip");

  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("r", 2.5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d[2]); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d){tooltip.text(function(d) { return d[3]; }); return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
      .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
      .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});

  svg.selectAll(".domain")
      .style("display", "none");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush);

  function brushended() {
    var s = d3.event.selection;
    if (!s) {
      if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, idleDelay);
      x.domain(x0);
      y.domain(y0);
    } else {
      x.domain([s[0][0], s[1][0]].map(x.invert, x));
      y.domain([s[1][1], s[0][1]].map(y.invert, y));
      svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
    }
    zoom();
  }

  function idled() {
    idleTimeout = null;
  }

  function zoom() {
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
    svg.select(".axis--x").transition(t).call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".axis--y").transition(t).call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll("circle").transition(t)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
  }
});
```

And, finally, html:

```
<body>
    <div class="one">
        <div class="two">
          <svg id="cluster" width="700" height="500"></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Aside from the tooltip, and the zoom being somewhat off center, everything seems to be working properly. I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working JS Fiddle: [ScatterPlot with zoom and tooltips](http://jsfiddle.net/wgekqczp/1/)

Major changes:

1. As you're appending the `brush` `rect` on top of the circles, the `mouse` events on the circles would never work. The order of the elements matters big time here, you see! So, here's what I did (moved brush appending code *ABOVE* the circles:

   ```
   svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush);

   svg.selectAll("circle")
   ...
   ```
2. I'm not sure why you were using `mousemove` when you want the tooltip only when you have the mouse *over* the circles. I changed the mouse events to this:

   ```
   .on("mouseover", function(d){
      tooltip.html(d[3]).style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px").style("visibility", "visible"); 
   }).on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
   ```
3. You had the `div` element (used as a tooltip) within the SVG. I'm sure that might've been done in a hurry. Here: I moved it outside of SVG:

   ```
   var tooltip = d3.select(".two")
     .append("div")
   ```
4. It's not recommended to use static numbers while setting the axes domains. You have the data and you know the `x` and `y` points to be fetched from, so just use [d3.extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent)

   ```
   x0 = d3.extent(points, function (d) { return d[0]; }),
   y0 = d3.extent(points, function (d) { return d[1]; })
   ```

Minor changes:

1. Using `domain().nice()` while setting the domains. It's really useful when you have negative values. Here's the [doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice)
2. Instead of using just 2 of your provided points, I generated a few random points and used it as the data: this clears up the zoom issue as well (in which I changed nothing as you had it working perfect)

   ```
   function generateRandomPoints () {
    var points = [];
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
      points.push([Math.random()*30 - 15, Math.random()*20-5, i, 'Cluster '+ (i+1)]);
    }
    return points;
   }
   ```

Here's a snippet putting together all of the above:

```js
  var data = [
  {
    "points": generateRandomPoints()
  }
];
  
  
  function generateRandomPoints () {
   var points = [];
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
     points.push([Math.random()*30 - 15, Math.random()*20-5, i, 'Cluster '+ (i+1)]);
    }
    return points;
  }
  
  var points = data[0].points;

  var svg = d3.select("#cluster"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height");

  var k = height / width,
      x0 = d3.extent(points, function (d) { return d[0]; }),
      y0 = d3.extent(points, function (d) { return d[1]; }),
      x = d3.scaleLinear().domain(x0).nice().range([0, width]),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(y0).nice().range([height, 0]),
      z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  var xAxis = d3.axisTop(x).ticks(12),
      yAxis = d3.axisRight(y).ticks(12 * height / width);

  var brush = d3.brush().on("end", brushended),
      idleTimeout,
      idleDelay = 350;

  var tooltip = d3.select(".two")
      .append("div")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", "10")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .style("background", "#ffffff")
      .text("a simple tooltip");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush);
      
  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { 
      return x(d[0]); 
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { 
      return y(d[1]); 
      })
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d[2]); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
       tooltip.html(d[3]).style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px").style("visibility", "visible"); })
      .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});

  svg.selectAll(".domain")
      .style("display", "none");

  function brushended() {
    var s = d3.event.selection;
    if (!s) {
      if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, idleDelay);
      x.domain(x0).nice();
      y.domain(y0).nice();
    } else {
      x.domain([s[0][0], s[1][0]].map(x.invert, x));
      y.domain([s[1][1], s[0][1]].map(y.invert, y));
      svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
    }
    zoom();
  }

  function idled() {
    idleTimeout = null;
  }

  function zoom() {
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
    svg.select(".axis--x").transition(t).call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".axis--y").transition(t).call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll("circle").transition(t)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>



<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <svg id="cluster" width="700" height="500"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It appears as though I made a couple of simple yet critical mistakes. Thank you for the clear, detailed explanations.

Comment: Exactly. The "major changes" mentioned are simple ones but yes important ones. Glad I could help. :)